# Deploying SailsJS to Openshift

Tags: node.js, sass, openshift, sails.js

I managed to deploy application to Openshift, set port/host/db. But my app isn't working still, and it looks like my Gruntfile isn't run properly.

I have created hook inside `openshift/action_hooks` called `pre_start_nodejs`, with following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
export NODE_ENV=production

# If there is a grunt file, run $ grunt prod
if [ -f "${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}"/Gruntfile.js ]; then
 (cd "${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}"; node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt prod)
fi
```

but when I push my code to openshift, it says this

```
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: failure
remote: Activation status: failure
remote: Activation failed for the following gears:
remote: 539077bd5973caf0320000d0 (Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to  execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/539077bd5973caf0320000d0/nodejs)
remote: Deployment completed with status: failure
remote: postreceive failed
```

I also receive this warning regardin Sass:

```
remote: Warning: 
remote: You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to work.
```

Tried to install Sass with just `gem install sass`, but looks like it didn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You surely use `grunt-contrib-sass` - right?
That grunt-module need ruby and sass installed on the server.

try

```
grunt-sass
```

instead - that should help.

Comment: yes, "grunt-contrib-sass" is installed. I tried using package that you proposed, and locally it works fine, but on the server it's not installed, here's what I got. http://paste.ofcode.org/8Hcbs8Qw3AL82s4tdqq8eS

Comment: you have to replace grunt-contrib-sass with grunt-sass in your package.json and push the new package.json

Comment: yes, exactly what I did, but somehow node-sass can't be installed on remote server. I'm trying to find solution for that now :/

Comment: post you complete log plz

Comment: here's the longer log http://paste.ofcode.org/FbvMDERe5FZX6VeXCSUJMz, hope that now I pasted everything that could help. i'm still wrapping my head around it.

Comment: I deleted application and deployed it again. Looks like something different is happening, but again node-sass.http://paste.ofcode.org/eMvRvuzz4uqNXhWeKS3xjB

Comment: Hmm seems to be a bug at node-sass (dep of grunt-sass). Can you please check what version is installed at local? (see: node_modules/grunt-sass/node_modules/node-sass/package.json) I have 0.8.6 (make npm install grunt-sass a day ago).

Comment: mine is "version": "0.9.1" locally. I'll try with that one. Strange is that it works locally, but on server it fails while installing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55212/discussion-between-user3351722-and-ned).

Comment: Thanks to @user3351722, I managed to deploy it successfully, by defining older version of grunt-sass (0.12.1).